# SQL Server datatype differences for strings

Tags: sql-server

I wonder about the difference between different data types in SQL Server to store strings.

For example `ntext`, `nvarchar(X)`, `varchar`, `nvarchar(max)` etc.

What could be the advices in terms of flexibility, resource usage and performance?

Comment: Read this already answered question here for more clarity..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4187677/difference-between-different-string-types-in-sql-server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- All the string types the `N` are **unicode** - 2 bytes for each characters, will store things like Cyrillic, Asian, Arabic, Hebrew alphabets - while those without the leading `N` are not unicode (only properly store Western European / ASCII characters)
- `TEXT` and `NTEXT` are deprecated - don't use those anymore - use `(N)VARCHAR(MAX)` instead - see the [relevant MSDN documentation on that topic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx) for details
- `NVARCHAR(X)` is a "normal" string, max. of 8000 bytes of data (4000 Unicode or 8000 non-Unicode characters) - stored in the regular page in SQL Server
- `NVARCHAR(MAX)` is a special type, up to 2 GB of storage (1 billion Unicode characters) - but it requires special handling in storage, more effort needed, performs a bit slower than regular strings; use **only** when absolutely needed

Answer (score 0):

refer to the link below for difference between nvarchar and varchar then choose the best for you

[What is the difference between varchar and nvarchar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/144283/what-is-the-difference-between-varchar-and-nvarchar)

Answer (score 0):

For normal english letters use the varchar and for any other languages and foreign characters use nvarchar.
varchar uses 1 byte per charcater to store and nvarchar uses 2bytes per character.